# Query Update MySQL 5.0 vs 5.7

Tags: mysql, time, query-performance

I have a problem with query performance. I have query update with join like this :

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN (SELECT table2.a, table2.b 
        FROM table2 
        JOIN table3 ON(table2.x = table3.x) 
        JOIN table4 ON(table4.o = table3.o) 
        GROUP BY table3.o) table_temp ON(table1.key = table_temp.key)
SET variable = table2.b;
```

In MySQL 5.0 its no problem, that query fast in process. But since I change with MySQL 5.7, that query is slow process. In MySQL 5.0 just need a second time to process them, but in MySQL 5.7 I got in minutes for finish it. What is I must do it?

Comment: Is the new server indexed the same as the old server

Comment: Im using full backup and restore it to new MySQL version.

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans?

Comment: `GROUP BY table3.o` ... the bad news is that your query is invalid.  The good news is that if you tell us what the query is supposed to be doing, we might be able to fix it.

Comment: Sorry im wrong write Group By on there. It should be "GROUB BY a".

Comment: Why i must compare with execution plans? That query good before I change a version. Problem is when I change MySQL version and then its slow process

Comment: Comparing the plans may give us clues of what to look at next.  Without more details, we are flying blind.  There were possibly a thousand changes to the Optimizer between 5.0 and 5.7.

Comment: @Wisnu - which tables are `a` and `b` in??

Comment: @RickJames on table2

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`, preferably for both versions.

Comment: EXPLAIN cannot be using on MySQL 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im done with change method using Cursor and work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tuned your mysql 5.7 installation like recommended in this link ?

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/

Comment: still same, make other user locking and slow process